# Of what would Yosef been suspect in Ya'akov's eyes (Rashi on Breishit 50:16)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, yosef, vayechi, genesis-bereishith

Rashi on [Breishit 50:16](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=662) comments on the beginning of the verse "Our father commanded.." that Ya'akov made no such command, but the brothers said this because of peace and that Yosef was not **suspect in his eyes**."

Suspect of what??

Comment: @Fred - Got it now. I deleted my comment, as the answer below came in meanwhile. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78944/2091

Answer (score 8):

They told him that Yaakov left a request of him to forgive the brothers and not take revenge on them as recorded in the next passuk. Rashi is saying that Yaakov never suspected Yosef of harboring vengeful thoughts, And never left this command. However the brothers misrepresented the truth in order to guaranty themselves peace. They apparently did suspect Yosef might take revenge on them if not for his father commanding otherwise.

Comment: +1. I don't think it was so much to guarantee themselves peace per se, as it was to engender peace between themselves and Yosef. In the words of Rashi (*Y'vamos* 65b, s.v. *avicha tziva*), יעקב לא צוה אלא הם שינו מפני דרכי שלום. And, as the midrash puts it (B"R 100:8, statement of R' Shimon ben Gamliel), גדול השלום שאף השבטים דברו דברים בדוים בשביל להטיל שלום בין יוסף לשבטים. (Interestingly, see the variant in *Y'rushalmi Pe'ah* 1:1 and *Vayikra Rabba* 9:9, which say the verse, not the brothers, spoke falsely for the sake of peace).

Comment: @Fred i debated whether to translate the shalom here in a neutral sense the way you present it or the way I did. I'm still on the fence and might switch. I'll tell you my reasoning. The shinui for shalom by Hashem telling Avraham that Sarah laughed about herself was a way to prevent animosity, namely so that Avraham would not develop ill feelings against Sarah. To keep things neutral, Hashem was mishaneh.

Comment: @Fred cont. Here however we have the (formerly) ill willing brothers accusing Yosef of that same ill will, something he was completely free from. This is a one sided argument already in existence in their heads. Their shinui for peace had nothing to do with keeping Yosef happy, but rather their own well-being. In fact it hurt him so badly that he cried from it. I therefore translated it as the selfish act that it was.

Comment: @DanF Perhaps you can consider accepting this answer if it sufficiently answers your question.